# If this method is wrong then why interpreter excuting it half?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am absolute beginner in programming, I am doing zed shaw's python hard way. I was playing with function than I did

```
movies(mov1 = raw_input("first movie "), mov2 = raw_input("second movie "))
```

Now interestingly function does asking me for the input, so `raw_input` is working. But after that it's showing

```
TypeError:movies() got an unexpected keyword argument  'mov1'
```

My question is: If this is syntactically wrong then why start executing at all and why not syntactic error?

My function definition was:

```
def movies(sci_fi, thriller):
    print "So you like %r movie!!" %sci_fi
    print "So you like %r movie!!" %thriller
    print "Man those movies were awesome!!"
    print "Now movie is finished..."
    print "Get back to work. \n"
```

Comment: It's not syntactically wrong in the sense the the interpreter can't figure out the series of steps to take. It's a runtime error that the interpreter can only (reasonably) know about "halfway through".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have a syntax error. You have a *runtime* error.

Python is a highly dynamic language. Since functions are *objects*, other code could replace your function at any time during the runtime of your program, so Python won't know *until you call the function*, that you are passing in keyword arguments that the function doesn't support.

If you did this:

```
old_movies = movies
def movies(mov1, mov2):
    return old_movies(mov1, mov2)
```

somewhere else in your program and *then* used

```
movies(mov1 = raw_input("first movie "), mov2 = raw_input("second movie "))
```

your program would succeed.

Comment: Truth to be told I didn't understood your answer and what you did.Pardon me, I am a very slow learner.

Comment: @UmeshUpadhyay: I 'renamed' your existing function (I created another reference to it), then *replaced* the old name with a new version. Now your `movies(mov1 = raw_input("first movie "), mov2 = raw_input("second movie "))` function call works as this version has `mov1` and `mov2` arguments.

Comment: I tried,I got you.I was looking that can i directly set a variable by asking user in a function argument itself.It would reduce the lines I have to write.And i can do it.Its working fine.Thank you very much you taught me very important thing. :)

Comment: @UmeshUpadhyay: you don't *have* to use keyword arguments; you can just use `movies(raw_input("first movie "), raw_input("second movie "))`

Answer (score 1):

It's not a syntatic error. Its a "runtime" error. Your `movies` method does take two parameters. It only finds that your parameters are wrong when it goes to call the movies method and provides a parameter named `mov1` (or `mov2`)

Answer (score 1):

*raw_input* runs **before** the call to *movies* happens. 
Python is an interpreted language, so the signature of the *movies* function is not checked against your call (which gives wrong names to the arguments).

Comment: Oh Yes!! it's interpreted than it goes only in forward direction in a  line.So when it encounters a function it waits for it to finish but since both raw_inputs finishes before  function does, It running raw_input fine but throw error in function... Right?

Comment: I think you got the idea. In other words, to evaluate *movies* it needs the result from *raw_input*. This works fine. But then *movies* expects the arguments *sci_fi* and *thriller* and gets *mov1* and *mov2* instead. Then it rightfully complains ;)